# Eclipse SWT: GC stringExtent returns different values for same string

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I use a test button as GC's receiver to measure string length. Code snippet

```
String testStr = "some-test-string";
GC gc = new GC(testBtn);
System.out.println("Unit width " + gc.stringExtent("x").x);
System.out.println("Test width " + gc.stringExtent(testStr).x);
gc.dispose();
```

On the window, I clicked the test button twice without doing anything else. The test width got different values. First it was 140 and second time it was 121. If I clicked the button more times, it would stay as 121. But the unit width never changed, it is always 9.

How can I make gc return a fixed value for the same string? In addition, is there any "official" way to solve the problem such that given a shortened width, what would be the text value on a receiver (eg. a button or label) based on the current text value? That is, how to get the substring of the current text value to make the receiver have the new width (which is shorter than the original width)? Thanks.

Comment: Try setFont() for a Button before gc.stringExtent()

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Mac. Show us a full test program demonstrating the problem.